How to best add rafters on top of rafters?
My roof from the 1960s is supported by 2x6 rafters, some 16ft long, with perlins and ties to hold everything together. It’s all in decent shape, but it’s a bit older and I want to make sure it stays that way (with weather changing and all). Particularly my rafters start to feel a little thin and I’m looking to insulate my roof so these rafters just don’t provide a whole lot of strength or much space for insulation (even filled with the highest R-value I wouldn’t meet code in the area where I am [Westchester, NY]).
In short, I’m looking to increase the size of my rafters and short of replacing them, the best I can think of is adding another 2x6 (or thicker) on top. I read in some places this can be done with a continuous bead of glue, several truss plates in both sides overlapping both rafters and (hurricane?) straps to pull them together. I’m wondering how much strength this would add and if there’s any problems I’m not foreseeing.
Does anyone have experience or thoughts on how best to approach this situation?
Many thanks!

Is the space below the rafters living space or just an attic?  You usually insulated just above the living space and keep the roof deck ventilated and cool.

As a broad statement, adding lumber onto lumber doesn’t produce anywhere near the strength you’d hope for. Glue = 0 from an engineering calculation perspective. Sistering a 2x8 would get you somewhere in the range of r35 with spray foam.

The space below the rafters is attic space; we plan to convert some of that attic space into a vented cathedral ceiling and that’s mostly the reason for wanting to be able to put more insulation in there. We need R38 for normal roof and R48 (or thereabouts) for cathedral. I was thinking of sistering, but then we’d only add minimal space for insulation. Could I somehow bolt the beams together?

@AloysiusDefenestrate the glue I consider more of a ‘keep the second piece exactly in place’ kind of solution and then apply with full nailing regiment Simpson Strong Tie LSTA18 or 24 wrapped around the two every two or three feet or so. That would certainly add some strength, wouldn’t it?

Photos, my man.

Have you looked into an unvented layer on top of the existing roof? You’d get insulation without extensive modification of the existing. And it’s for a professional engineer on site to say, but I doubt that your existing roof is inadequate. (Largely because purlins reduce the open span of rafters.)

Wood usually does not weaken with age, so sixty plus years, it will be as good/strong as when it was built.  Some locations might gain from a stronger roof/better attachments, but is location specific.  If extra strength is not needed, but only a deeper depth for insulation plus roof ventilation, makes life easier, just slap another 2x6 on.  Extra strength might need a rebuild of the roof.
